# Replacing a variable in php file

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

Im looking to figure out a way to replace variable inside a php file then send that modified file thru FTP.

I wish to delete items by keyword for each of my clients... so i dont have to log into their websites everytime. I just need to change the value to a variable inside a php file. I'm having trouble escaping out the $ or something... Is there an eaiser way to say (change $variable to $value in $file)? or overwrite a file a specific?

Here is an example of the file i want to modify

```
<?php 
mysql_connect(host,user,pass);
mysql_select_db(dbName);

$keyword = ""; //I want to replace this line

mysql_query("delete from products where product_name like '%$keyword%'");

?>
```

I want to run a script on my main servers similar to this

```
<?php

 $handle = fopen("keyword_remover.php", "w");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                  $write_line .=  str_replace("\$keyword=\"\";", "\$keyword=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword'])."\"", $line);
                }
            } else {
                // error opening the file.
            }
            fputs($handle,$write_line);
            fclose($handle);

//make sure that FTP connection is valid
            $connection_url = "ftp.".$client_domain;

            // Set up a connection
            $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($connection_url);

            // Login
            if (ftp_login($ftp_conn, $client_user, $client_pass))
            {
                $connected = "1";
            }else{
                $connected = "0";
            }

            if($connected == "1")
            {
                //FTP connection worked, lets push the script and run it!
                $local_dir = "keyword_remover.php";
                $remote_dir = "remote_path/keyword_remover.php";
                ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_dir, $local_dir, FTP_ASCII);
                $script_url = "http://".$client_domain."//"keyword_remover.php";
                scriptHit($script_url); // Hit the script with curl here
                sleep(1);
                ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $remote_dir);


                echo $script." ran on " .$client_domain."<br>";


            }else{
                echo "Could not connect to FTP: ". $connection_url."<br>".$client_user."<br>".$client_pass;
            }
            ftp_close($ftp_conn);

?>
```

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: Wow, that's over-complicating the matter. Just have PHP read a config file or something and upload the changes to those.

Comment: In addition to what Phil mentions, you should see an anti-pattern in what you are doing.  Writing PHP scripts to modify variable (or is this REALLY a constant) values in a PHP file is just lunacy.  This is what database, config files, content management systems, admin panels, etc. are meant to do.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the comments, its as simple as...

```
 $keyword = file_get_contents("keyword.txt");
```

and let FTP to overwrite keyword.txt when you change your word.

*nb keyword.txt contains the key word and nothing else.*

Comment: Thank you very much.. Didn't really consider the option of having my keyword as a single file.. Good idea mortimerCat  ;)